# Filtering X Axis by using custom intervals in kibana visualizations

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

I am new to ELK stack and I have a requirement as the following. When a Kibana visualization contains a X axis, can we add an interval options list to filter the X axis like the drop-down list in Kibana Discover. Curently I'm using Elasticsearch 7.0.1 and Kibana 7.0.1.
Currently we can define the interval when we create a visualization. But I need that to be selected when it is displayed inside a dashboard. Is it possible to add a interval options to a visualize to be filtered in the dashboard level?

I expected a list down with the interval options in the visualization and must be able to select an option to filter the visualization.